# unable to connect to default instance using it's full name

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-connection, sql-server-2016

I am developing an app that needs to get from a user a server name or address and a db name and build a folder structure based on that. The problem is that in order to have the same folder for all the different ways there are to get the path to the instance (localhost, ip address, etc.) i'm running the following Query:

```
select cast(SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName')as varchar)+'\'+@@servicename
```

on the target server and set my folder structure based on that, and in that format saves the connection that the user gave (doesn't matter if i got ip or a server name, there is one connection string for all).
My problem is that when the instance is the default instance on the target machine, I cant seem to connect using `MACHINE_NAME\MSSQLSERVER`. I can only log in using the machine without instance name. So I need to either find a way to connect to the instance using its full name (preferred) or to find a way figure out if the targeted instance is the default one. 
Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Not all SQL Server installs have an 'instance name'.  Those are called 'default instances', and they're addressed solely by machine name.  You'll want to account for that in your script so that if there isn't an instance name, you don't try to use it to connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'MSSQLSERVER' is reserved for default instance, so you can

```
SELECT CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName')AS VARCHAR)+ CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('MSSQLSERVER', @@SERVICENAME, 1) >0 THEN '' ELSE '\'+@@SERVICENAME END
```

Comment: are you 100% sure that there is no way to change the default name during the installation?

Comment: You specify the instance name on installation. If you don't specify an instance name, you get a default instance. After installation, you cannot change this without uninstalling/re-installing.

Comment: You can specify the instance name during installation. If you don't, then it uses the default.

Comment: Can you please run the query against all your SQL instances? I'm interested in learning the results.

Comment: I will rephrase, are you sure that the above query will be correct in all cases? can a named instance have the name MSSQLSERVER? can a default instance have a different service name, which is not MSSQLSERVER?

Comment: @Wendy running that query gave me the correct answer, but all my DBs are identical and with very little configuration. Before releasing it in a product its very important for me to verify that there is no case in which it will give a wrong answer. I'm asking it since I'm not sure what are the exact rules of @@ServiceName

Comment: The documentation is pretty clear: "@@SERVICENAME returns 'MSSQLSERVER' if the current instance is the default instance; this function returns the instance name if the current instance is a named instance."  This seems safe to use. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/servicename-transact-sql